# Vbscript - Script to check if each subfolder exists

Tags: vbscript, directory

I'm working on a script that basically copies folders and files from a server to local computers. While working on this, I've found that I'm in need of a function of some sort that basically takes a string of a full folder path, splits it up and checks each folder if it exists. If it doesn't, create the folder.

So, I was thinking of a smart way of doing this so I can reuse the code later.
I would like it to take one argument, the string of the full path. And the code does the rest.

Edit: This is the completed code from Jean-François Corbett. I'll give you over 9000 thank you's!

```
Public Sub createFolderStructure(ByVal strFullPath)
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' How many levels are there?
    nLevel = 0
    strParentPath = strFullPath
    Do Until strParentPath = ""
        strParentPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strParentPath)
        nLevel = nLevel + 1
    Loop

    For iLevel = 1 To nLevel
        ' Figure out path for directory at level iLevel
        strParentPath = strFullPath
        For j = 1 To nLevel - iLevel
            strParentPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strParentPath)
        Next

        ' Does this directory exist? If not, create it.
        If objFSO.FolderExists(strParentPath) = False Then
            Set newFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strParentPath)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you coding without `Option Explicit`?? If so, you're asking for trouble!

Comment: Yeah, but that's because I know what I'm doing ;) Nah, really. I use Option Explicit usually. But not when I'm just sketching code up like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got `objFSO` anyway, why not use its [`GetParentFolderName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22dyy47c%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`FolderExists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) methods. Really, `FileSystemObject` has most of this figured out already, so spare yourself some pain; no need to reinvent the wheel.

**EDIT**: Here's an example of what I think you want to do. Adapt as you see fit.

```
strFullPath = "C:\aaaa\Test\Vbscript" ' 4 levels

' How many levels are there?
nLevel = 0
strParentPath = strFullPath
Do Until strParentPath = ""
    strParentPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName(strParentPath)
    nLevel = nLevel + 1
Loop
Debug.Print nLevel ' nLevel = 4 for this example

For iLevel = 1 To nLevel
    ' Figure out path for directory at level iLevel
    strParentPath = strFullPath
    For j = 1 To nLevel - iLevel
        strParentPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName(strParentPath)
    Next j

    ' Does this directory exist? If not, create it.
    Debug.Print iLevel, strParentPath, FSO.FolderExists(strParentPath)
    If FSO.FolderExists(strParentPath) = False Then
        Set newFolder = FSO.CreateFolder(strParentPath)
    End If
Next iLevel
```

Comment: Nice! This was exactly what I was thinking :) I couldn't believe this wasn't created from before :) Ok, so I'll try this and update the code when it's done :) I guess I should check msdn more often..

Comment: Hmm, do you have any pointers on how to do this? I mean, I can get the parent folder name and check if that exists. But I can't create folders AND subfolders in one go can I? Meaning, if the GetParentFolderName gives me "C:\Temp\Test\Vbscript", then I can't just create that, with subfolders and all can i?

Comment: Wow this really did do the trick! :) Just had to edit a few things, but this is sound! But I've gotta go through it to make sure I actually get what's going on here. But I will! :)